# Kafka 1.0 reseting offset doesn't reset all partitions to 0

Tags: apache-kafka

When resetting kafka consumer offsets to earliest, it keeps some partitions with offset > 0

`$ kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --group group1 --topic topic1 --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute`

Shows:

```
TOPIC             PARTITION  NEW-OFFSET
topic1            4          0
topic1            1          6153734
topic1            3          0
topic1            2          0
topic1            0          0
```

Why is there no 0 for partition 1 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that earliest offset is trully 6153734

Found it using `--reset-offsets --to-offset 0`

That outputs

```
WARN New offset (0) is lower than earliest offset. Value will be set to 6153734 (kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$)
```

Comment: And is it possible to set it to 0 ? And if so, how ?

Comment: Probably by deleting the topic as the first offset is 6153734